# Move sub-chapters to the next page, if they are displaying at the end of a page (using openXML)

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I´m creating a word document with openXML. This file includes several pages and chapters. Chapters of level 1 are automatically placed on a new page using

```
...new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page });
```

. Now I would like to write a logic that moves sub-chapters to the next page, if they are at the end of a page and no content is following them (on **this** page).

**Short:** I´m looking for a way to minimize postediting on my newly created word document.

Comment: For Chapter Headings of Level 1 consider moving the break into the style rather than inserting a physical break (in word this is the Paragraph.PagebreakBefore property).  For all headings you should use the paragraph.KeepWithNext and Paragraph.KeepTogether to ensure that the heading text will stick to the next paragraph and not split over a page.  The keepwithnext property will work if there is some next.  You'll have to do the research on how to apply these properties using openXML.

Comment: Sounds reasonable! Thanks for your fast answer :)